# How to loop string array in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I would like to know how I can do a for loop to do a for loop in order to display the players names names alongside the rolls of their dice depending on the number of players entered by the user.

```
if (num_of_players == 1) {
    players[0] = player1;
}
if (num_of_players == 2) {
    players[0] = player1;
    players[1] = player2;
}
if (num_of_players == 3) {
    players[0] = player1;
    players[1] = player2;
    players[2] = player3;
}
if (num_of_players == 4) {
    players[0] = player1;
    players[1] = player2;
    players[2] = player3;
    players[3] = player4;
}
if (num_of_players == 5) {
    players[0] = player1;
    players[1] = player2;
    players[2] = player3;
    players[3] = player4;
    players[4] = player5;
}
if (num_of_players == 6) {
    players[0] = player1;
    players[1] = player2;
    players[2] = player3;
    players[3] = player4;
    players[4] = player5;
    players[5] = player6;
}

for (String y : players) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The first dice rolls " + y);
```

Comment: You can't do this in a for loop, because of your variables `player1`, `player2` etc. But you can write `if (num_of_players >= 1) players[0] = player1; if (num_of_players >= 2) players[1] = player2; ...`.

Comment: Seems like there might be something flawed with your design if you have a seperate variable for each player named playerN. Show a bit more of the code to provide some context, and you'll get more helpful answers.

Comment: What do you mean rolls of their dice? Please elaborate exactly what you need help with.

Comment: Why aren't you using a loop to read the names directly into the array?

Comment: @HerbWolfe A `for` loop can't be used for input here because the indices are being fed by different variables named player1, player2, etc.

Comment: @MasterYushi there is no need for player1, player2, etc,  if the names are being input directly into an array. Based on this code it is likely that the player names are being input using a similar if then else pattern.

Comment: @MasterYushi For example. I have code in my program asking the user to enter the number of players between 2-6. Then depending on the number entered by the user I want it to output the dice rolls corresponding to the number of users. For example if the user enters 2 player I want the output to be "Player one dice one rolls 2", "Player one dice two roll 6" and "Player two dice one rolls 5" etc.

Comment: @gallen5522 So you want to print  two random dice throw values between 1-6 for every player in the players array?

Comment: @MasterYushi Yes but my problem is printing the player names depending on how many players are in each game.

Comment: @gallen5522 What is the size of the players array? You can use a while loop to loop through the strings in players array until you hit an empty String or a null object based on how you initialized the players array.

Comment: @MasterYushi I'm taking user input to determine the amount of players partaking(2-6). The user may enter 4 as the numbers of players. Then there will be 4 players in the array... Player1, Player2, Player3 and Player4. I'm not sure what you're saying about the while loop. I need the loop to print "Player1 rolls....." ,"Player2 rolls..." etc. until the number of players the user entered it reached

Comment: @gallen5522 So you take the size of the array as user input, then declare the array with the specified size, right? And what does the array store? Strings? ints? What do the player1, player2, etc. variables hold in them?

Answer (score 3):

Since you've already got 6 `player` variables, you can just put these into an array, and then take a copy of part of the array. There's no explicit loop required:

```
String[] aPlayers = {player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6};
System.arraycopy(aPlayers, 0, players, 0, num_of_players);
```

---

Note that you're only setting the first `num_of_players` elements of `players`, you will have `null` elements at the end (or whatever happens to be in those elements already); and the for loop will still iterate over those elements.

If this is not what you want, you might want to consider assigning a smaller list to `players`:

```
players = Arrays.copyOfRange(aPlayers, 0, num_of_players);
```

Or you can wrap the array in a list and take a sublist:

```
for (String y : Arrays.asList(players).subList(0, num_of_players)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure loops are applicable here, but this simplification is possible, given each block repeats the work of the previous ones...

```
if (num_of_players == 1) {
    players[0] = player1;
}
if (num_of_players >= 2) {
    players[1] = player2;
}
if (num_of_players >= 3) {
    players[2] = player3;
}
if (num_of_players >= 4) {
    players[3] = player4;
}
if (num_of_players >= 5) {
    players[4] = player5;
}
if (num_of_players >= 6) {
    players[5] = player6;
}
```

Another way to tackle this would to be create an array and use that with your loop. Better still player1, player2 variables would be an array to start with.

```
String [] playersArray = {player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6};

for (int i = 0; i< num_of_players; i++) {
    players[i] = playersArray[i];
}
```